# Concurrent Requests Limit with IIS on Windows 10 Home/Pro/Enterprise

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr, windows-10

I developed a ASP.Net Web application with SignalR (WebSockets).
I installed it on IIS on a Windows 10 Home Machine. Since SignalR uses an persistent connection between the server and the client I have the problem that only 3 connections can be handled with this setup.

What is the concurrent connection limit on IIS 8.5 on Windows 10 Pro or Windows 10 Enterprise?

Is there an other option to host this application at home, without having to install Windows Server?

Comment: This link says 10 connection limit on Windows 8 Pro/Enterprise, so I'd expect at least that for Windows 10.  http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit  I didn't post this as an answer because it is for windows 8, not 10.

Comment: try IIS express

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this link where detailed instructions are posted to raise the concurrent client limit to 40.  I've encountered no errors after making these modifications to a Windows 7 Pro workstation used as a server for multiple sites.  The values might work also with Windows 10 Pro.

A.R.C. Increase IIS Connection Limits: https://www.ingenuityworking.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/1227.a-r-c-increase-iis-connection-limits.aspx

Comment: This doesn't do anything. The value is already set to max, and IIS throttles internally.

Comment: I know this is only 1 year later, but the link you have provided is a dead link now