# how many concurrent requests settings for IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, concurrency, python-requests

How many concurrent requests can be executed in IIS 8.5?

I could not find proper values for how many concurrent requests can be executed in IIS 8.5

As I found out below 2 different values:

1. By default IIS 8.5 can handle 5000 concurrent requests as per `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` settings in aspnet.config
2. In machine.config, the maxconnection is 2 per CPU as default. So if have 6 core CPU then 12 concurrent requests are possible by default.

So I would like to know that Point 1 is right or Point 2 is right for concurrent requests for IIS 8.5.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you are using ASP.NET application, the concurrent requests executed can vary based on the way the application code is written and the framework version you are using to run the application (2.0, 3.5, 4+ etc). Also you are confusing with max connect with concurrent requests. Both are two different things.

For more detailed understanding please read msdn blog [ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.5, IIS 7.0, and IIS 6.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/)  .

To summarize

1. MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU in
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\2.0.50727.0` determines the number of concurrent requests per CPU. By default, it does not exist and the number of requests per CPU is limited to 12
2. If your asp.net application is written entirely with asynchronous requests, the default `MaxConcurrentReqeustsPerCPU` limit of 12 is less and increase this setting `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` to a very high number.
3. In v4.0, the default for `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` to 5000

[Maxconnection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) is the setting per HTTP protocol.Any application can only make two concurrent requests to any server.e.g. Your browser(IE 6,7) can make only two connection to your [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). But for speed improvement ,many of the browsers currently make more than 6 simultaneous connections (vary in Chrome, Firefox and IE). Similarly when your server application make a request to a web service or a rest API, the client is your application and maxconnection enforces that for the same server (rest end point), you are allowed to make only two connections .

> To increase maxconnection in an ASP.NET application, set
> System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit programatically,
> from Application_Start, E.g. You can set this to Int32.MaxValue

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

According to this article there is also limitations when running on different Windows versions:

https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit

**Max concurrent requests**

**Windows 8:**

*3 requests*

**Windows 8 Professional**:

*10 requests*

**Windows RT**:

*N/A since IIS does not run on Windows RT*

I assumed (and tested on Windows 10 Home Edition) that on 8 and above this limitations still exists.

Comment: does anyone know what the limitations are for windows 10? I am having troubles with unit tests calling layered http services and timing out. the issues seem to have been manifested lately. maybe there has been a change in the licensing restrictions here? Alredy asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024015/concurrent-requests-limit-with-iis-on-windows-10-home-pro-enterprise

Comment: Also from that article, it's worth noting that Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 allow an unlimited amount of simultaneously requests.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 properties are not the same as I think you are implying they are.

**MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU**

Controls the number of incoming requests being handled per CPU

**maxconnection**

Controls the maximum number of outgoing HTTP connections that you can initiate from a client to a specific IP address.