# How to limit concurrent request processing at the same time for action in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have limited resources and I need to limit number of concurrent requests, ideally action-level constraints. Is there some attribute?

ASP .NET Core 2.2, hosted in IIS

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think this is a setting in IIS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244683/how-many-concurrent-requests-settings-for-iis-8-5

Comment: Consider using a [Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Clever, semaphore can be usefull, thank you.