# IIS 10.0 How can I see requests queued behind the 10 concurrent requests listed in Worker Processes?

Tags: windows, iis

In Worker Processes -- View Current Request, only the 10 concurrent request are listed.

1. How can I see everything else that is waiting on these 10 to finish?
2. How can I increase the 10 concurrent request limit?
3. Is there a way to limit how long a request can run?

Any advice is most appreciated!

---

---

Here's Windows IIS version information.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions Your Windows 10 can only support 10 concurrent connections. All other requests are not even processed as no more connections are allowed. Use a Windows Server machine if you want to dig further into web app performance measurement, and questions become only valid there.

Comment: Is this limit 10 per app pool?  We are thinking about splitting the website to segment different business needs.

Comment: As far as I know, maximum concurrent requests and maximum connections are different, just refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244683/how-many-concurrent-requests-settings-for-iis-8-5#answer-45251604). And as mentioned by other member, for better performance, please use the windows server machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use a windows server machine at this time.

Comment: Do assets such as js, css, json, and image files count toward the 10 concurrent limit?