# Getting 504 Gateway Time out error in .net core api

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi

We are getting a 504 gateway time out for this ASP.NET Core 6 Web API while doing performance test. This is the API:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetGUID(GUIDModel model)
{
    String result = await BAL.GetGUID(model);
           
    return Ok(new { guid = result });
}
```

Business layer

```
public async Task<string> GetGUID(GUIDModel model)
{
    string result = await  DAL.GetGUID(model);

    return result;
}
```

So, this model which contains some of the parameter against which GUID will be generated and stored in DB And generated GUID will be return to the Web API.

However, when we are doing performance test we are getting 504 gateway time out for almost 50% requests are made.

For example if we are passing 1000 concurrent request then 500 request have this error.

Our API's are hosted on EC2 instances (c6i.xlarge) with 8gb, 4vCPUS are configured.

This is the one of the simplest of API we have which do not have any kind of complex transaction. Still, we are not sure why we are getting such error.

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming this is running out of IIS on the EC2? Maybe something with that is off.  If you are getting exactly 500 requests failing out of 1000, I am wondering if you have some concurrency limit in place without knowing.

Comment: Yes, its on IIS server. So, where we need to check concurrency limit to solve this issue?

Comment: possibly.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244683/how-many-concurrent-requests-settings-for-iis-8-5 maybe?

Comment: Ok.So this need to be handled from infra level and code level seems to be ok?

Comment: In the code you provided, nothing seems abnormal with it.  So I suspect something around configuration or infrastructure is off yes.